# Nginx 404 (Not Found) only for rails images on AWS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, nginx

Im testing my app in production mode and running into a weird problem.  The image assets aren't loading on the webpage.  All the css and javascript are loading fine but any image gets a `404 (Not Found)` from nginx.  Im pushing my app with docker to AWS services.  When I precompile the assets the images are included in the output so they should be there:

```
I, [2017-08-30T12:10:50.092655 #7]  INFO -- : Writing /livingrecipe/public/assets/default-user-d39e051d757a0f45602b6065147cec0a307c6a2a070834f6fe6fc2b0fc914207.jpg
I, [2017-08-30T12:10:50.104846 #7]  INFO -- : Writing /livingrecipe/public/assets/default_recipe-be8d509a8e34dfec514c097b119753d4aaadbfd1dd6747e3c868ed454b8a36b3.jpg
I, [2017-08-30T12:10:50.108486 #7]  INFO -- : Writing /livingrecipe/public/assets/edit-4e381318428d71d55ed0cbdc32b4ce99db6622140c6e7c751ae0f1bfb40d3963.png
I, [2017-08-30T12:10:50.111606 #7]  INFO -- : Writing /livingrecipe/public/assets/favorite-91432751e505915d80cf4e24d7a8d0abd3493d05d2d447c1cebb055d99757ac8.png
I, [2017-08-30T12:10:50.115720 #7]  INFO -- : Writing /livingrecipe/public/assets/icon_email-203dcd7bdcf7559d742f76a9d8c21e98694d45b9556b29ab9ce286a7dd37af11.png
I, [2017-08-30T12:10:50.118457 #7]  INFO -- : Writing /livingrecipe/public/assets/icon_facebook-0140437ec6cb29bc6ac6f8505f05f11603a430298e48c1ea483f7de390ba34a9.png
I, [2017-08-30T12:10:50.121393 #7]  INFO -- : Writing /livingrecipe/public/assets/icon_google-2a98026430dddc53539d283c04a2ad4b50536c93d0becadb03f3f61443e52c9c.png
I, [2017-08-30T12:10:50.125228 #7]  INFO -- : Writing /livingrecipe/public/assets/star-half-db15fb9b3561d5c741d8aea9ef4f0957bd9bc51aa1caa6d7a5c316e083c1abd5.png
I, [2017-08-30T12:10:50.127714 #7]  INFO -- : Writing /livingrecipe/public/assets/star-off-6aaeebdaab93d594c005d366ce0d94fba02e7a07fd03557dbee8482f04a91c22.png
I, [2017-08-30T12:10:50.130083 #7]  INFO -- : Writing /livingrecipe/public/assets/star-on-fd26bf0ea0990cfd808f7540f958eed324b86fc609bf56ec2b3a5612cdfde5f5.png
I, [2017-08-30T12:10:50.132442 #7]  INFO -- : Writing /livingrecipe/public/assets/unfavorite-7000a53c81f55cf94c88031a8529f847e5a6abd7460e0e54ae0b581b0cde85a3.png
```

And here is my default.conf file for the nginx:

```
upstream PLACEHOLDER_BACKEND_NAME {
  # The web app.
  server PLACEHOLDER_BACKEND_NAME:PLACEHOLDER_BACKEND_PORT;
}

# Redirect 'www' addresses to the non-www version, and also take care of
# redirects to HTTPS at the same time.
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name www.PLACEHOLDER_VHOST;
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
  # "deferred" reduces the number of formalities between the server and client.
  listen 80 default deferred;
  server_name PLACEHOLDER_VHOST;

  # Static asset path, which is read from the PLACEHOLDER_BACKEND_NAME
  # container's VOLUME.
  root /PLACEHOLDER_BACKEND_NAME/public;

  # Serve static assets.
  #
  # gzip_static is enabled because the assets are already gzipped to a maximum
  # level due to Rail's asset pipeline.
  #
  # Add headers to set the maximum amount of cache time.
  #
  # We can do this because the Ruby on Rails asset pipeline md5 hashes all of
  # the file names for us. When a file changes, its md5 will change, and the
  # cache will be automatically busted. Other frameworks can do this as well.
  location ~ ^/assets/ {
    gzip_static on;

    # Set a maximum cache time period and null out a few headers to address
    # certain browsers from occasionally requesting cached content.
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
    add_header Last-Modified "";
    add_header ETag "";
  }

  # Ensure timeouts are equal across browsers.
  keepalive_timeout 60;

  # Disallow access to hidden files and directories.
  location ~ /\. {
    return 404;
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;
  }

  # Allow optionally writing an index.html file to take precedence over the upstream.
  try_files $uri $uri/index.html $uri.html @PLACEHOLDER_BACKEND_NAME;

  # Attempt to load the favicon or fall back to status code 204.
  location = /favicon.ico {
    try_files /favicon.ico = 204;
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;
  }

  # Force SSL connections on agents (browsers) who support this header.
  add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains;";

  # Load the web app back end with proper headers.
  location @PLACEHOLDER_BACKEND_NAME {
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ssl on;
    proxy_redirect off;

    if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = "http") {
      return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    proxy_pass http://PLACEHOLDER_BACKEND_NAME;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am going to answer from experience, although I had the same problem with Nginx + Django. What saved my situation is giving a user that runs the server (might be `www-data`, in my case was me) privilege to access images. Yes, it sounds stupid since it has permissions on other files, but that helped. Try

```
sudo chmod -R 750 /root/of/website
```

This will recursively give permission 750 to all files in that directory. Hope it helps!

**Note:** It might not be the problem so please do not downvote if it doesn't help.

Comment: so add that in the nginx conf file?

Comment: No, run it in your shell (I assumed you are using linux for some reason. If not so, please say).

Comment: If this doesn't work then post exact nginx logs in your question

Answer (score 0):

So it was a simple mistake of wrong way to reference the assets.  In rails I was using this:

```
<%= asset_path('/assets/image.png') %>
```

which in development mode still showed the assets but in production it couldnt find it cause it already adds the assets folder so was looking in assets/assets/image.  Changed everything to:

```
<%= asset_path('image.png') %>
```

Like it should be and it worked just fine.